# Is Appendix 2 for sponsors who have settled in the UK only?

Tags: visa, uk-visa, uk-citizens

In my Spouse VISA application i found out that there is Appendix 2 that i have to fill and it says **Use the appendix 2 (financial requirement form) to tell us how you meet the financial requirement when you are applying to join a partner, child or other family member who is settled in the UK.** , but my sponsor is a British citizen and has not been settled in the UK, so does this apply to me?

Comment: Where has your sponsor been residing?

Comment: she has been living in the UK for all her life, but she is British i mean her family are not immigrants who settled in the UK.

Comment: I see.  In UK immigration law, a British citizen is considered to be settled in the UK.  So it probably does apply to you, but I don't have time to look in detail just now.

Comment: Do you recommend any source to get a definite answer for this? Thank you for your help